# Azure CosmosDB Account: How much time does regenerated account key take to become effective?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to regenerate CosmosDB account key using [Regenerate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/databaseaccounts/regeneratekey) method. And getting this response:

```
{
    error:{},
    status:"Enqueued"
}
```

And when I am trying to list the keys after some time, I get the regenerated account key.

If I am using that regenerated key do do any operation (such as list databases or collections) immediately after regenerating, I am getting authorization error.

```
{
    "baseException": {
        "code": 401,
        "body": "{\"code\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\\ndbs\\n\\nwed, 18 jul 2018 06:51:30 gmt\\n\\n'\\r\\nActivityId: 34881a63-c107-49f7-9de0-aeeaee1da57c, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.0.0.0\"}",
        "activityId": "34881a63-c107-49f7-9de0-aeeaee1da57c"
    }
}
```

So how much time does it usually take to become effective?

Comment: Well, Microsoft says that they use this key to encrypt all the data at rest so I would expect the time to be relative to how big your database is.

Comment: Hi Nick, can you please share a link to documentation which says that account key is used to encrypt all the data at rest.

Comment: This page is talking about Encryption at rest in general https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-encryption-at-rest and in this presentation a Microsoft Employee lets us know that the key is used as part of the encryption. https://youtu.be/8RiHSDf7xBs?t=498 However I could be wrong and it might be a different key.